# PDO database connection error?

Tags: 7, database

Super strange, my site was up and working fine yesterday. Today, I navigate to my home page and I'm thrown this series of errors:

> Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in DatabaseConnection->__construct() (line 321 of /var/www/html/includes/database/database.inc).
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /var/www/html/includes/lock.inc).

To the best of my knowledge, this only occurs when the database connection settings are incorrect in the settings.php file, but all of mine are correct (and have been for quite some time). Any idea why this would suddenly change and throw this error? I'm stumped.

Comment: Is your db and file system on the same server? Error says name resolution failed which indicates its DNS resolver issue. Has the DNS records updated recently?

Comment: @miststudent2011 No, DNS records still the same :/ I'm able to navigate to my url and it tries to load my Drupal home page, but instead I get the error above. It's almost as if my database login info has changed... I even tried changing my master db user and password, but no luck connecting with that either.

Comment: Update: Oddly, it seems it's just my Public IP and url that stopped connecting properly, but my Private IP works just fine. No idea why  this is an issue all of a sudden. I'm using AWS and I've contacted them, and they've confirmed everything is setup correctly and that it's an issue on their end with the public IP. On that note, while they fix the public IP, is it a bad thing to use the private IP in the settings.php file? Or would one strongly advise against this? Thanks! @miststudent2011